# <a> inside of a <header> won't move to the bottom

Tags: css

I have my code here in css for the a inside the header:

```css
header {
    display: block;
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    width: 100%;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    min-width:200px;
}

header img {
    float: left;
 }

header a {
    color: white;
    font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 200%;
    text-decoration: none;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<header>

  <div class="header-image-container">
    <img src="benny.jpg" alt="Benny logo">
  </div>

  <h1 class="site-title"><a href="#">Benny's List</a></h1>

</header>
```

I just want the a that is inside the header to be down towards the bottom of the header but no matter if I put margin or padding, it won't move at all. Thank you guys for any help!

Screenshot: https://i.stack.imgur.com/356b6.jpg

Comment: Can you add header section to question.

Comment: When asking a question about a problem caused by your code, you will get much better answers if you provide code, people can use to reproduce the problem. See [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

You probably just need to add `clear` for your hyperlink

```css
header {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 200px;
}

header img {
  float: left;
}

header a {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-decoration: none;
  float: left;
  clear: both; /* Added */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/100x100">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need of using floats when u don't need them next to each other, have a look at the below working snippet without using `float: left`, hope it helps :)

```css
header {
  display: block;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 200px;
}

header img {
  /* float: left; */ /* removed */
  display: block; /* Added */
}

header a {
  color: white;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-decoration: none;
  /* float: left; */ /* removed */
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/g/80/80">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</header>
```

Comment: Thank you for your help man :D But I actually do want the image right next to the hyperlink! The way the header is supposed to go is *image* *link/name of website* right next to each other! *EDIT* I just realized by saying move to the bottom, I made it confusing! I just want my hyperlink to be placed lower than what it is now, as it is almost center with the header but I want it towards the bottom!

Comment: can u add your header code too... and expected result as a scribbled sketch/screenshot, that will help all understand the requirement :)

Comment: Absolutely! I will edit the post for the header code and screenshots!

Answer (score 0):

```css
header {
  background-color: #000000;
  color: #ffffff;
  width: 100%;
  height: 150px;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 200px;
}
header img {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
   display: block; 
}
header a {
  color: #ffffff;
  font-family: 'Roboto Slab', sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-size: 200%;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <img src="https://image.ibb.co/nsrpRz/111.jpg">
  <a href="#">Link</a>
</header>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just play with negative value of margin-top of img according to your requirement. 
It will work. Below is the css code:

```
header img {
   float: left;
   margin-top: -10px;
}
```

Just tweak the value of margin-top according to your requirement.